# Shaped svg background

Tags: html, css, svg

I have to code design like on the picture below:
[image]

and it's responsive version looks like that:
[image]

Im Have no idea how to code background with this shape and also with shaped line before background.

Should I just create two very big svg's for bg and line or do it other way ?

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: The blue part could be just a CSS Gradient, but for that shape you would have to create a svg shape, it would be much easier. Also, what stroke are you talking about? I don't see any :|

Comment: the blue shaped line one the bottom of the shape

Comment: Oh, I though it's because of hovering the shape. Anyway, the simplest way would be to create two svg files, since these will be very lightweight and require only a few minutes to be created. There is a possibility to make these with canvases, but I don't think it's worth the time and effort.
And just a remark, I think the blue stroke looks bad and confusing :)

Comment: Forgot to mention, it doesn't have to be two very big svg files, they should only long enough to cover that middle section, above it would be a css gradient and below it could be a simple css white background.

Comment: i need to create it very large to place it in :after and add background-size: contain. I can't use cover because cover does not scale while changing size of window. Also is there any posibility to extend parent element gradient to it's :after pseudoelement?

Comment: i have tried using background-size: 100% auto, and it's making great work with resizing svg in :after, however while scaling it it's not keeping it's position. Any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

How I would approach this is by stacking three SVGs on top of one another.  Using `position: absolute` SVGs inside a `position: relative` container element.

The three layers are:

1. A background graph shape with a grey fill
2. A mid-ground SVG with the three boxes
3. A foreground graph shape that has a blue stroke, but no fill, so you can see layers #1 and #2 behind it.

We can make the two graph shapes `preserveAspectRatio="none"` so that they stretch to the width of the screen, We can also make it so that they share the same path definition to save space.

The middle layer we make `preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid meet"` so it hugs the right hand side of the screen. That's just one way, of several we could have used, to achieve that effect.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #111166;
}

#svg-container {
  position: relative;
}

#svg-container > svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

#background-graph {
  fill: #f8f8f8;
  overflow: visible;
}

#foreground-graph {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #111166;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" display="none">
  <!-- The graph shape. Used in two places below. -->
  <polygon id="jagged" points="0,360, 65,325, 100,340, 120,330, 130,335, 225,270, 255,295, 280,275, 290,290, 340,250, 360, 255, 400,235, 400,2000, 0,2000" style="vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>

<div id="svg-container">
  <svg id="background-graph" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <use xlink:href="#jagged"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="boxes" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid meet">
    <rect id="box1" x="30" y="10" width="225" height="175" fill="#fafafa"/>
    <rect id="box2" x="75" y="155" width="265" height="190" fill="#fff"/>
    <rect id="box3" x="260" y="80" width="125" height="70" fill="#fafafa"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="foreground-graph" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <use xlink:href="#jagged"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```